# Translation of ferric and ferrous to German

Tags: nomenclature

I am not sure if this question belongs to the Chemistry or German forum.

My question is basically in the title. Are there good translations of ferric and ferrous to German which retain the meaning of Fe(III) vs. Fe(II)?

I.e. How would you translate something like:

```
The CAS(20,20) represents the smallest possible active space
  for this all-ferric model compound, with its 20 unpaired electrons [...]
```

to German.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

German wikipedia pages for $\ce{FeCl2}$/$\ce{FeCl3}$ use the title names

Eisen(II)-chlorid resp. Eisen(III)-chlorid,

so it is almost identical to usual scheme element(ON) halogenide. (Eisen = iron).

So ferric = iron(III) = Eisen(III), ferrous = iron(II) = Eisen(II)}.

The model "element(ON)" is the preferred IUPAC way.

The alternative may be to use ferri-/ferro- prefixes.

Comment: This is definetely the right answer for single-core complexes. But if I have a multi-core complex and want to emphasize that all irons are Fe(III), then 
"Eisen(III)-Modellverbindung" does not emphasize it in the same way as "all-ferric" does.
So I will wait a bit more before accepting it as answer.

Comment: Is "Alle(s)-Eisen(III)-Modellverbindung" applicable?

Comment: That sounds strange, at least to my ears. I guess I stick to "Eisen(III)-Modellverbindung" or "Eisen(III)-Modellkomplex". Thank you for the suggestions.